# How to add Custom GlyphSeries to LineSeries in visx XYChart?

Tags: d3.js, charts, x-axis, lineseries, visx

I have implemented a Visx XYChart component with LineSeries.
[Codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-galileo-m54ygc?file=/Example.tsx)

Requirement:

1. I need to display a Glyph to indicate the start and end of the individual LinePath, and only if the LinePath starts or ends in between the start or end of the x-axis.
   The x-axis plots weekly data for a year(52 weeks), if the data has less than 52 weeks of data points, then it means LinePath begins or ends somewhere in between the x-axis.
2. I need the x-axis to display the January month name as well.

How do I approach to solve this problem?